# Usage of "provides" keyword-argument in python's setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

I am working on a fork of a python projet ([tryton](http://www.tryton.org/)) which uses setuptools for packaging. I am trying to extend the server part of the project, and would like to be able to use the existing modules with my fork.

Those modules are distributed with setuptools packaging, and are requiring the base project for installation.

I need a way to make it so that my fork is considered an acceptable requirement for those modules.

EDIT : Here is what I used in my setup.py :

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    provides=["trytond (2.8.2)"],
    ...
)
```

The modules I want to be able to install have those requirements :

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=["trytond>=2.8"]
    ...
)
```

As it is, with my package installed, trying to install a module triggers the installation of the trytond package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t use provides, it comes from a packaging specification (a metadata PEP) that is not implemented by any tool.  The requiremens in the `install_requires` argument map to the `name` in your other setup.py.  IOW, replace your `provides` with `setup(name='trytond', version='2.8.2')`.

Comment: I would like to avoid using the same name than the base project in order to avoid confusion.
I am currently experimenting with pypatch to dynamically patch the existing library, but disapointed that neither pip nor easy_install implements provides :(

Comment: Ah, I missed that this was a fork.  Current tools don’t support provides; discussiong is ongoing to make future tools better (PEP 426).  At present you need a different name (simple and robust) or different version numbering scheme, and projects wanting your fork have to explicitly require the changed name or version.

Comment: The fact is that I would like to be compatible with other modules which are requiring trytond when installing. So I think i will stick with PyPatch as I cannot modify the setup requirements of those external resources. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you are building rpms, it is possible to use the setup.cfg as follows:

```
[bdist_rpm]
provides = your-package  =    0.8
obsoletes = your-package
```